# Is this the correct way for ASP.NET web application to do authentication?

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication

ASP.NET Web Forms applications.

I checked our company's legacy code, the way they do login is like this:
when user is validated against database with (username, password), they set a session:

```
Session["authenticated"] = "true";
```

Every page other than `login.aspx` is inherited from a class named `SecurePage`. In `SecurePage`'s `OnInit()` method, it checks

```
if (Session["authenticated"] != null)
```

if true, means authenticated, otherwise means not. So basically the way to do authentication is to see if there is a session named `authenticated`.
This seems the most crude and intuitive way of doing authentication... I want to ask: is this safe?

Another thing I feel strange is that in the `web.config`, they have this:

```
<authentication mode="Windows" />
```

Shouldn't it be

```
<authentication mode="Forms" />
```

since these are web applications? Users credentials are stored in database and these users are outside clients (not internal users).

A slight different version also does this after user is validated against database:

```
FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie( username, true );
```

what does this do? Besides this statement in `login.aspx`, I don't see any other pages have any code related to auth cookie. Do we need to set auth cookie by ourselves in code or does .NET framework handle this for us already?

Still another version have the following:

```
FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(login, false, 60);
HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName,    FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(ticket));
Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
```

what does this do? Do we need to set this cookie by ourselves in code? or does .NET framework handle this for us already?

These web appliations were developed a long time ago, though I am not sure when. I suspect it is .NET 1.0 era? From my understanding since .NET 2.0, 
it has this ASP.NET membership thing, and we can just use `<authentication>` and `<authorization>` tags in `web.config` (and subfolder `web.config`) to achieve the goal of authentication and authorization. Isn't it? Can anyone give me a history of ASP.NET framework authentiation mechanism? (membership -> simple memebership -> Identity?)

Comment: Whether it's a web application or not doesn't matter as far as Windows vs Forms authentication. I think a lot of the rest of your questions can be answered by looking at the documentation regarding the methods. And there's no need for `Session["authenticated"]` since there is a `Request.IsAuthenticated` property.

Comment: I believe, with <authentication mode="Windows" /> in the web.config, Request.IsAuthenticated will always be true. So, what Session["authenticated"] should be fine.

Comment: In the approach that I described above, does it has anything to do with Windows or Forms authentication? I changed it from Windows to Forms and it works the same. The code does authentication all by itself - check database and set a session, it seems not relying on anything of .net framework. So how can `Request.IsAuthenticated` be set at all?

Comment: Firstly, you can't set the Request.IsAuthenticated to true, its a read only property. When you do the FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie, you are authenticating user, and Request.IsAuthenticated is set itself, and .net does that. The only thing is that instead of using the config settings, its a code based approach. I personally would use code based authentication, since it overrides what is default behavior and does what you have written.

Comment: Thanks. So is `FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie` statement required when doing authentication the right way? (I don't think do authentication by setting a session variable like our company does is the correct way). Is it because of this statement that `<authentication>` and `<authorization>` tags in `web.config` take effects? in other words, if there is no `FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie` statement, `<authentication>` and `<authorization>` tags will not have any effect?

Answer (score 0):

```
<authentication mode="Windows" />
```

Above should be used mostly in intranet website, because it's like saying use the computer(windows pc) authentication to access the resource. However, this will never work, since inherited class has a method to validate session key value for a login.

You should make sure that the code redirects user to login page in case the session key is not found. That means, in the else section of below code, you should take users to login page to try again. Which I am sure is happening.

```
    if (Session["authenticated"] != null)
{ /*user is authenticated*/ }else{ /*redirect to login*/ }
```

Its is recommended to use `<authentication mode="Forms" />` if the website is accessible over the internet. Other benefit of using this setting is that you can set default and login page.

Finally, `FormsAuthenticationTicket` is a class with property and values that are used when working with Forms authentication to identify authenticated users.

Read through msdn article to know more about asp.net membership.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh26yfzy%28v=vs.140%29.aspx

Comment: Thanks. The code does have an `else` part that redirect user to login page. So in the way that they implement authentication, that `FormsAuthenticationTicket` is totally meaningless? - since they set authentication mode to `Windows` in `web.config`.

Comment: Even if its windows in web.config, it wouldn't matter, since your code is overriding every setting. However its recommended to switch from windows to forms in web.config, while you are using website over internet.